# What is the most effective tool you've used to track changes in a CVS repository?

Tags: cvs, version-control

I'm in Quality Assurance and use Fisheye to track checkins to CVS. What other options do people use?

We have tens of thousands of files and have plans for migrating to Team Foundation Server's code management tool 'at some point' When we do that, there will be lots of information that will be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) provides a nice web interface to CVS (or SVN) and is reasonably easy to setup. It does not provide the same functionality as fisheye, however. I haven't tried the integration w/ a SQL DB backend though, I believe that will add some fisheye-like capabilities.

[CVSTrac](http://www.cvstrac.org/) also provides a web interface, wiki, ticket system, and other features. I haven't set it up on our repository, but it does provide some fisheye-like features as well.

Comment: We did go through with setting up the MySQL backend, and it's pretty useful. It was a bear to put together though, and I ended up having to hack the python quite a bit to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a mail sent to you at each commit...  Look into the [CVS Book](http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#Commit%20Emails).

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, this doesn't help with CVS, but I'd recommend switching to subversion, which is designed to be a CVS replacement.  Then you can use [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) to follow checkins, as well as manage change tickets and documentation. It was well worth the effort in my own projects.

But if you have to use CVS, there's always [CVSweb](http://www.freebsd.org/projects/cvsweb.html)